# Fluent nhibernate map IDictionary<int, string>?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

After searching around the web I found a mapping that gets most of the job done:

In my class I have:

```
public virtual IDictionary<int, string> _properties { get; set; }
```

And in the mapping:

```
HasMany(x => x._properties)
     .AsMap<string>(index => index.Column("PropertyID").Type<int>(),
                    element => element.Column("Value").Type<string>())
                   .KeyColumn("ID")
                   .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_DeftoProperties")
                   .Table("Definition_Property")
                   .Not.LazyLoad()
                   .Access.Property()
                .Cascade.All();
```

Which results in this table definition:

```
create table Definition_Property (
        ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
       Value NVARCHAR(255) null,
       PropertyID INT not null,
       primary key (ID, PropertyID)
    )
```

However I need the "Value" to be longer that 255 and changing the mapping to:

```
element => element.Column("Value").Type<string>().Length(500)
```

doesn't have any affect on the table generation.

If I map it using an hbm file:

I get the table I expected.

Any ideas on how to set the length fluently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...Element("Value", x => x.Length(300))...
```

Comment: That doesn't do it, I changed my code to: `HasMany(x => x._properties) .AsMap("PropertyID") .Element("Value", x => x.Length(400)) .EntityName("PropertyID") .KeyColumn("ID") .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_DeftoProperties") .Table("Definition_Property") .Not.LazyLoad() .Cascade.All(); ` and it still generates the table with Value as NVARCHAR(255)

Comment: It worked for me before posting it here. I'm using  FHN V 1.2.0.721 [(+)](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt295&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv).

Comment: Hmmm.  That's the same version I'm using.  I even changed the field name to Valuezzz to make sure that it is using the mapping when creating the table.  It may be something with my setup.

Comment: I'm still scratching my head on this one. I took a look at the generated hbm files and the element in there is getting the length set correctly: `<element type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" length="400"> <column name="Value" /> </element>` but the generated SQL is still showing `Value NVARCHAR(255) null`

Comment: Sorry VahidN, I'm unchecking your answer.  I feel this is a bug in Fluent nHibernate 1.2.  The AsMap is adding the length to the ElementPart of the field instead of the ColumnPart.  I downloaded the source and have been running it in the debugger and watching what's going on.  I haven't figured out where to make the change in the code but if I move the length attribute from the Element to the Column in the generated hbm file and use that in my configure then the SQL table is generated correctly.

Comment: Ok VahidN, I'm rechecking your answer.  You are correct, the issue was fixed in 1.2.0.721.  I was using the .712 version.  Need to remember my glasses when reading small numbers.